# PHP Cli Pass Repeating Command Line Arguments

Tags: php

I'm was wondering if anyone knows of a native function to parse command line options in PHP via the cli that allows repeating options?  getopt doesn't like something like:
program.php -w "WARNING1" -w "WARNING2"

I would make use of the pipe symbol and get the user to pass me WARNING1|WARNING2 however because each option is a regex they may use this already, and I've seen perl working this way.

So any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could certainly do this by manually reading and parsing the values out of the global `$argv` variable. That will contain all command line values: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve multiple command line options by

- Using some separator character and options variable with getopt
- Use regular getopt without -w flag

  **php script_name.php Jarrod "cake, tea and ice cream"**

will give you, `jarrod` and `cake,tea and ice cream` as arguments

Also take a look here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php
and read more about options and long options.

Comment: Many thanks, it's not quite what I wanted, but the reply is much appreciated.